# How does Angular's validation for an invalid form field work?

Tags: angular, validation

What are the conditions for a form field in Angular to be invalid? Can I define it by specifying a custom rule set or is it done internally by Angular? Does it vary according to the type of the form field? Also, are there any differences between the `invalid` form validation in AngularJS and Angular?

Comment: working on angular 2 or more ???

Comment: yeah! Angular 4 to be precise.

Comment: No, as far as properties concern there is not any specific type added such as required, dirty, pristine, touched etc. are almost common in both version of angular and angularjs

Comment: but in terms of creating the form, they are rapid changes you can check form types in angular documentation such as template driven(conventional angularjs practices), Reactive and dynamic forms

Answer (score 1):

In angular you can do validation of your field using internal validation available and you can also create your own validation i.e. custom validation and use it.

For doing that you can follow this guide : [Form Validation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation)

there are two approach for validation in angular

1. Template base
2. Reactive Form

in both you can use already given validation and define custom validation. my preference if you have more fields go for Reactive form as its easy to maintain.

From the documentation , if you want to check sepcific error on field then you need to check `errors` array on field

for example if you have done like this

```
  this.heroForm = new FormGroup({
    'name': new FormControl(this.hero.name, [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(4),
    ]),
```

then you can check specific error by doing this i.e. checking `errors` on field

```
  <div *ngIf="name.errors.required">
    Name is required.
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="name.errors.minlength">
    Name must be at least 4 characters long.
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks! i've went through the official docs but i just wanted to be more clear about how a form field, say an input with type email becomes invalid? is it the conventional email validation and null/empty check stuff that angular gives us internally?

Comment: @Pragun - if you have defined field call name then you will get this , name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched) for field , and for detail error you can check this name.errors.required or name.errors.minlength" , what i mean to say for specific error you have to check errors array